# Fluxus - undefined identifier gl and gh keeps returning 0.0

Tags: opengl, 3d-engine

I'm trying to get the scripts running of the hackpact of mndl.hu but I keep running in to the error.

```
undefined identifier gl
```

I googled and came across the follow

```
(define (gl n)
       (log (+ 1 (gh n))))
```

But gh keeps returning 0.0 so simply replacing gl with gh won't work ether.